# ORACLE Performance: (Hash) Join vs Subselect With Order By's in Huge Tables

Tags: oracle, performance, join, hash, subquery

I've got the following (abstract) problem in `ORACLE 11g`:

- There are two tables called `STRONG` and `WEAK`.
- The primary key of `WEAK` is a compound consisting of the primary key of `STRONG` (called `pk`) plus an additional column (called `fk`).
- Thus we have a generic `1:N` relationship.
- However, in the real world application, there is always exactly one row within the `N` `WEAK` rows related to an entry of `STRONG` that has a special relationship.
- This is why there is an additional `1:1` relationship realised by adding the column `fk` to `STRONG` as well.
- Furthermore, it might be worth noting that both tables are huge but well indexed.

The overall picture looks like this:

[image: UML]

Now, I have to define a view showing rows of `STRONG` along with some additional columns linked by that `1:1` relationship. I tried two basic approaches:

### Subselects

```
SELECT
(SELECT some_data1 FROM weak WHERE weak.pk = strong.pk AND weak.fk = strong.fk) some_data1,
(SELECT some_data2 FROM weak WHERE weak.pk = strong.pk AND weak.fk = strong.fk) some_data2
FROM strong
```

### Left Outer Join

```
SELECT
weak.some_data1,
weak.some_data2
FROM strong
LEFT OUTER JOIN weak ON weak.pk = strong.pk AND weak.fk = strong.fk
```

I first thought that the "Left Outer Join"-way has to be better and I still think that this is true as long as there is no `WHERE/ORDER_BY`-clause. However, in the real world application, user query dialog inputs are dynamically
translated into extensions of the above statements. Typically, the user knows the primary key of `STRONG` resulting in queries like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_view
WHERE the_view.pk LIKE '123%' --Or even the exact key
ORDER BY the_view.pk
```

Using the "Left Outer Join"-way, we encountered some very serious performance problems, even though most of these `SELECT`s only return a few rows. I think what happened is that the hash table did not fit into the
memory resulting in way too many `I/O`-events. Thus, we went back to the Subselects.

Now, i have a few questions:

### Q1

Does Oracle have to compute the entire hash table for every `SELECT` (with `ORDER_BY`)?

### Q2

Why is the "Subselect"-way faster? Here, it might be worth noting that these columns can appear in the `WHERE`-clause as well.

### Q3

Does it somehow matter that joining the two tables might potentially increase the number of selcted rows? If so: Can we somehow tell Oracle that this can never happen from a logical perspective?

### Q4

In case that the "Left Outer Join"-Way is not a well-performing option: The "Subselect"-way does seem somewhat redundant. Is there a better way?

Thanks a lot!

---

### EDIT

Due to request, I will add an explanation plan of the actual case. However, there are a few important things here:

- In the above description, I tried to simplify the actual problem. In the real world, the view is a lot more complex.
- One thing I left out due to simplification is that the performance issues mainly occur when using the `STRONG => WEAK`-Join in a **nested join** (see below). The actual situation looks like this:

  - `ZV` is the name of our target view - the explanation plan below refers to that view.
  - `Z` (~3M rows) join `T` (~1M rows)
  - `T` joins `CCPP` (~1M rows)
  - `TV` is a view based on `T`. Come to think of it... this might be critical. The front end application sort of restricts us in the way we define these views: In `ZV`, we have to join `TV` instead of `T` and we can not implement that `T => CCPP`-join in `TV`, forcing us to define the join `TV => CCPP` as a nested join.
- We only encountered the performance problems in our productive environment with lots of user. Obviously, we had to get rid of these problems. Thus, it can not be reproduced right now. The response time of the statements below are totally fine.

### The Execution Plan

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name                         |     Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                              |     717K|    73M|       | 13340   (2)|
|   1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                              |     717K|    73M|    66M| 13340   (2)|
|   2 |   VIEW                           |                              |   687K|    59M|       |     5   (0)|
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                              |   687K|    94M|       |     5   (0)|
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                              |     1 |   118 |       |     4   (0)|
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | Z                            |     1 |   103 |       |     3   (0)|
|   6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | SYS_C00245876                |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)|
|   7 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | SYS_C00245876                |  1798K|    25M|       |     1   (0)|
|   8 |     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE        | TV                           |   687K|    17M|       |     1   (0)|
|   9 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                              |     1 |    67 |       |     2   (0)|
|  10 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T                            |     1 |    48 |       |     2   (0)|
|  11 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C00245609                |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|
|  12 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | SYS_C00254613                |     1 |    19 |       |     0   (0)|
|  13 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL              | CCPP                         |  5165K|    88M|       |  4105   (3)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

The **real question** is - how many records does your query return?

10 records only or 10.000 (or 10M) and you expect to see the first 10 rows quickly?

For the **letter case** the subquery solution works indeed better as you need no sort and you lookup the WEAK table only small number of times.

For the **former case** (i.e. the number of selected rows in both table is small) I'd expect execution plan as follows:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Id  | Operation                     | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |     4 |   336 |   100   (1)| 00:00:02 |
 |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                |            |     4 |   336 |   100   (1)| 00:00:02 |
 |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |            |     4 |   336 |    99   (0)| 00:00:02 |
 |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| STRONG     |     4 |   168 |    94   (0)| 00:00:02 |
 |*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | STRONG_IDX |   997 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| WEAK       |     1 |    42 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  6 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | WEAK_IDX   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
 ---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("STRONG"."PK" LIKE '1234%')
        filter("STRONG"."PK" LIKE '1234%')
    6 - access("WEAK"."PK"(+)="STRONG"."PK" AND "WEAK"."FK"(+)="STRONG"."FK")
        filter("WEAK"."PK"(+) LIKE '1234%')
```

If you see  FULL TABLE SCAN on one or other table - the optimizes impression could be that the predicate *pk LIKE '123%'* will return too much records and the index access will be slower. 
This could be a good or bad guess, so you may need to check your table statistics and cardinality estimation.

Some additional information follows

**Q1**

If Oracle performs a *HASH JOIN* the whole data source (typically the smaller one) must be read in memory
in the hash table. This is the whole table or the part of it as filtered by the WHERE/ON clause.
(In your case only records with pk LIKE '123%'  )

**Q2**

This may be only an impression, as you see quickly **first records**. The subquery is performed
only for the first few fetched rows.

To know the exact answer you must examine (or post) the execution plans.

**Q3**

No, sorry, *joining of the two tables NEVER potentially increase the number of selcted rows* but returns exact the number of rows
as defined in the SQL standard.

It is your responsibility to define the join on a unique / primary key to avoid duplication.

**Q4**

You may of course select something like `some_data1 ||'#'||some_data2` in the subquery, but it is in your responsibility 
to decide if it is safe..

Comment: Both tables hold roughly one million rows. **SELECT**s on that view usually return less than 100 rows.

Comment: **Q1 / Q2**

I was able the reproduce cases where the runtime of **SELECT**s fetching only one row by primary keys was about 20 times slower using the **Left outer Join**-way.

Comment: @zarpendorff What is it in absolute? 1ms to 20 ms? This will not scare me. Note also that you **should** see a drop of the response time in repeated query with the same parameters (as the index and data blocks are cached), so be sure to compare safely.

Comment: The difference is **~2.3sec** to **~50sec**. However, the response time was totally unpredictable (i.e. it sometimes became **worse** when repeated). As I said, I think this is a caching issue. We did not notice any performance differences when testing this thing. But in our productive environment (~1000 users), we quickly encountered an overflow of the **TEMP** tablespace. Now, the strange thing is that this does not happen with subselects. In fact, the **TEMP** tablespace does not seem to be needed at all for that matter. So I just assume that the performance has to better this way.

Comment: @zarpendorff both response times are inacceptable (I assume you columns some_dataN are simple VARCHARs - not large CLOBs). If the selected data is large, this may of course affect the sorting behaviour. Pls post execution plans.

Comment: OK, i have uploaded an execution plan. While doing so, I realized that I might be the key that we are using a nested join that is not defined on the actual tables but views built around them.

Comment: My guess is, that the problem is in the estimation of the cardinality of the join between `T` and `Z` this is `687K` - you said that it should be *less that 100*. This leads to the `HASH JOIN` and `FULL TABLE SCAN` on CCPP with 5M rows. My advice - get a `dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor` of a long running query and compare actual and estimated rows. If the number of rows is small (e.g. < 100) you definitively want all the joins to be NESTED LOOPs.